# Large select list options?

Tags: jquery, html-select

I need to have a user select their address in our address database (I'm in a local government agency) mostly so I can get their property pin #. In the past, we have prompted for addresses by first selecting street, then direction, then house number. This works but as always, I am looking for a better way. I found this [cool jQuery plugin](http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/) called Chosen that allows a person to start typing and it'll automagically search and find something in the list. I am thinking this would be a great way for someone to search for their address but as you can imagine, this list is quite large and is only getting bigger. I don't really want to send the entire list across the internet for one address.

I am thinking I need to have a web service return data like Google instant search does. After about 3 characters, I provides them with a list. Is there any jQuery (or other type) controls that can poll a web service as you type?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the [**jQueryUI autocomplete**](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/) widget. Sounds like it's just what you need.

Here's the description from the site:

> Autocomplete, when added to an input field, enables users to quickly
>   find and select from a pre-populated list of values as they type,
>   leveraging searching and filtering.
>
> By giving an Autocomplete field focus or entering something into it,
>   the plugin starts searching for entries that match and displays a list
>   of values to choose from. By entering more characters, the user can
>   filter down the list to better matches.
>
> This can be used to enter previous selected values, for example you
>   could use Autocomplete for entering tags, to complete an address, you
>   could enter a city name and get the zip code, or maybe enter email
>   addresses from an address book.
>
> You can pull data in from a local and/or a remote source: Local is
>   good for small data sets (like an address book with 50 entries),
>   remote is necessary for big data sets, like a database with hundreds
>   or millions of entries to select from.
>
> Autocomplete can be customized to work with various data sources, by
>   just specifying the source option. A data source can be:
>
> - an Array with local data
> - a String, specifying a URL
> - a Callback
>
> Expected data format
>
> The data from local data, a url or a callback can come in two
>   variants:
>
> - An Array of Strings: [ "Choice1", "Choice2" ]
> - An Array of Objects with label and value properties: [ { label: "Choice1", value: "value1" }, ... ]
>
> The label property is displayed in the suggestion menu. The value will
>   be inserted into the input element after the user selected something
>   from the menu. If just one property is specified, it will be used for
>   both, eg. if you provide only value-properties, the value will also be
>   used as the label.
>
> When a String is used, the Autocomplete plugin expects that string to
>   point to a URL resource that will return JSON data. It can be on the
>   same host or on a different one (must provide JSONP). The Autocomplete
>   plugin does not filter the results, instead the request parameter
>   "term" gets added to the URL, which the server-side script should use
>   for filtering the results. The data itself can be in the same format
>   as the local data described above.
>
> The third variation, the callback, provides the most flexibility, and
>   can be used to connect any data source to Autocomplete. The callback
>   gets two arguments:
>
> - A request object, with a single property called "term", which refers to the value currently in the text input. For example, when the
>     user entered "new yo" in a city field, the Autocomplete term will
>     equal "new yo".
> - A response callback, which expects a single argument to contain the data to suggest to the user. This data should be filtered based on the
>     provided term, and can be in any of the formats described above for
>     simple local data (String-Array or Object-Array with label/value/both
>     properties). It's important when providing a custom source callback to
>     handle errors during the request. You must always call the response
>     callback even if you encounter an error. This ensures that the widget
>     always has the correct state.
>
> The label is always treated as text, if you want the label to be
>   treated as html you can use Scott González' html extension. The demos
>   all focus on different variations of the source-option - look for the
>   one that matches your use case, and take a look at the code.

Comment: Oh sorry, I am looking at that since the first comment. Looks about like what i was looking for.